# Add tab completion for Git branches in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, autocomplete

When inside a Git repository, is it possible to add tab completion for branches to Powershell? For example:

`PS> git checkout ma`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

would result in

```
PS> git checkout master
```

Comment: I take it you don't want to use bash (git bash on Windows, I suppose)? You still might want to have a look at the git bash completion as a starting place on the git side, to see the git commands it uses to get its lists of possible completions. Obviously the tab completion customization itself will be completely different though...

Comment: @Jefromi, I prefer not to keep a separate shell open just for git (although it does bite me sometimes). Thanks for the suggestion, though. I didn't know this was available in bash.

Comment: For not having to deal with having a separate shell just for git, try this:  https://github.com/chriswalz/bit. Note I’ve worked on this but it suits this use case well

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For that to be possible, a git provider for PowerShell would need to exist.

After a quick search, something similar apparently exists, the bizarre but aptly named posh-git:

http://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

> A set of PowerShell scripts which
>   provide Git/PowerShell integration
>
> - Prompt for Git repositories:    The prompt within Git repositories can
>     show the current branch and the state
>     of files (additions, modifications,
>     deletions) within.
> - Tab completion:    Provides tab completion for common commands when
>     using git.    E.g. `git ch<tab>` -->
>     `git checkout`
>
> ### Usage
>
> See profile.example.ps1 as to how you
>   can integrate the tab completion
>   and/or git prompt into your own
>   profile. You can  also choose whether
>   advanced git commands are shown in the
>   tab expansion or only simple/common
>   commands. Default is  simple.

Comment: I thought I remembered it being possible to add the necessary stuff from msysgit to your path so you could run it from elsewhere?

Comment: @GabeMoothart Completion of branch names worked for me. Perhaps they have added support for that since your comment.

Comment: What is bizarre about the name POSH? POSH is short for Powershell

Comment: Side-note: post-git is (now?) referenced in the official git documentation: https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-PowerShell

Comment: In addition to following the rather technical documentation, you can also follow this simple [step-by-step guide](https://www.rodyvansambeek.com/blog/git-autocomplete-powershell-magic)

Answer (score 22):

I wrote this little PS "gem", if posh-git is too much.
Just put it in your [PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles) to be able to type `co`  (with a space) and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to trigger completion and cycle through the list of branches:

```
function co
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ArgumentCompleter({
            param($pCmd, $pParam, $pWord, $pAst, $pFakes)

            $branchList = (git branch --format='%(refname:short)')

            if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($pWord)) {
                return $branchList;
            }

            $branchList | Select-String "$pWord"
        })]
        [string] $branch
    )

    git checkout $branch;
}
```

UPDATE: refactored to return a list of branches when tab-completion invoked after space and no partial string can be matched. Will return "master" if this is only one branch

As a bonus, did you know you can call TortoiseGit from shell?

```
function dif
{
    TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:repostatus
}
```