# Can I setup auto-complete for git on Windows via cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, git, autocomplete

I've recently learned that on linux, git can be setup to autocomplete commands: If you type

`git br<TAB>`

Then it will complete it to `git branch`.

Can the same auto-completion be set up on Windows?

**Update** - I'm usually working with git via cmd.exe (I added git to my path). This question is about adding auto-completion to git on cmd, if that's possible.

Comment: I just tried the latest release of msysgit and autocomplete works for me by default.

Comment: If you're interested in how to do this for PowerShell, there's a [question with good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586722/add-tab-completion-for-git-branches-in-powershell) about that too.

Comment: The PowerShell option is the best for getting autocomplete for git in Windows, even if it strays outside the remit of the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use some form of bash to get it to work, either git bash that comes with msysgit or some other bash (which you need to setup to use the autocompletion used in git bash). With cmd.exe you will have no luck.

Look at this as a sign for you to leave old rusty cmd.exe behind. Enter the light of bash! : )

Comment: Not always an option even 10 years later :(

Answer (score 35):

Installing Clink seems to make this work by magic, verified in cmd, Console2, and ConEmu.

http://mridgers.github.io/clink/

UPDATE:  To get ConEmu and clink to work properly with the more recent versions, it was necessary to install clink into the ConEmu folder.  See https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/339 and https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/270 for more info.

Comment: clink works like gangbusters with cmd on Windows 7, would highly recommend for autocompletion

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. ralphtheninja: try running .bat or .cmd with bash - good luck!

Comment: Just installed clink on Win10, and it auto-completes the command. But it does not dig into your git repo to auto-complete branch-names. So, for me, the hunt continues.

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster Why not to use Git Bash?

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster So I was having this same problem...I just wrote some LUA scripts to make my experience with `clink` a little better: https://github.com/collink/clink-git-extensions/

Comment: Note that clink is now maintained at another repository: https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/. However, it require more installation steps then: https://github.com/vladimir-kotikov/clink-completions#installation

Answer (score 15):

For future readers, I have found that [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) combined with [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) is a beautiful git experience.

This is `powershell`, not `cmd.exe` though.

Comment: I would suggest installing Powershell Core, several major versions beyond what was pre-installed on my Win 10 machine and including enhancements such as the `&&` and `||` shortcuts, so that you can `git stash && git pull & git stash pop`

Comment: @AndrewSpencer thanks for the tip. I'll do that :).

Comment: posh-git works great! Just followed the instructions on the repo page and it autocompletes commands and repo-specific stuff! I've wanted this for so many years.

Answer (score 0):

### clink and powerful completions

1. Install the [maintained fork of clink](https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/).
2. Follow the instructions at https://github.com/vladimir-kotikov/clink-completions#installation.

### clink and branch completions

In case the above method is too complicated, you can have "lightweight" completion.

1. Install the [maintained fork of clink](https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/).
2. Download [git-autocomplete.lua](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ztomm/git-autocomplete-for-windows/main/git-autocomplete.lua) (which is maintained at https://github.com/ztomm/git-autocomplete-for-windows/).
3. Navigate to `%APPDATA%\..\Local\clink` (paste that in the address bar of Windows Explorer)
4. Move the downloaded `git-autocomplete.lua` to that folder.
5. Restart `cmd.exe`.

Note that this does not work for the above `git.lua`, because that lua file needs other lua files, too. See https://github.com/vladimir-kotikov/clink-completions/issues/166 for details.

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I just found the git auto-completion is not working on the traditional cmd.exe but did works if I enable the Windows sub-Linux feature, working pretty well on the Windows bash command line

[image]

Comment: I don't understand.  The start of your comment talks about cmd.exe but the picture is Power Shell.  Did your fix require Power Shell?  Power Shell stuff is useful here since some may be able to use it.  The OP came looking for cmd.exe solutions.  Some people are stuck in cmd.exe due to circumstances outside their control.